# Connecting via serial with Arduino comand line

Tags: serial, command-line, ino

Since [inotool](http://inotool.org/) is dead, I'm trying to transition over to Arduino's built-in [command line tool](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/build/shared/manpage.adoc).

It seems largely equivalent, but the one feature it seems to be missing is a serial interface. e.g. Running `ino serial` would open a simple serial interface to the Arduino, providing invaluable debugging info from any Serial.print() statements.

How is this accomplished with the current Arduino command line tool?

Comment: You may want to just use some other command line serial solution.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, Such as...?

Comment: Well, I use an ever-evolving custom solution, so won't be of much help with that...

Comment: What OS are you using? Putty, screen, minicom ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up simply switching to [ano](https://github.com/scottdarch/Arturo).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using linux, as I guess, you can look at [this archwiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Working_with_the_serial_console). Even if is a wiki relative to archlinux OS some informations explained are LinuxOS independendent.

For your needs, you can use screen command. Here is an example: remember to substitute the serial port with the one wich arduino is connected (usually /dev/ttyACM* or /dev/ttyUSB*) and to specify the right baud rate.

```
screen /dev/ttyACM0 9600
```